# Embed runtime dlls in fortran exe

Tags: windows, dll, fortran, exe, intel-fortran

I have an Intel Visual Fortran program built in VS Pro 2015. This program gets deployed on other computers but I can't count on the runtime DLLs being on other workstations. There is a way to tell VS to include necessary DLLs into the executable. I have used this before but can't find where the option is now.

Comment: Did you mean static compilation?

Comment: I don't think relates to static compilation. I would think it is a linker option. And I don't think it has anything to do with redistributable. The program gets an error not finding libifcoremd.dll. I have searched for an answer but none of the threads I've found have been helpful.

Comment: That library IS a redistributable runtime library. Why do you say it is not? Why have all other question not been helpful? Have you actually tried static compilation (even just `-static-intel`).

Comment: Well now I'm being told that referencing Intel Visual Fortran is incorrect. The current Fortran version is Parallel Studio XE Composer Edition for Fortran Windows. Everything is defined through dialog boxes, not command line options.

Comment: It does not matter how you call it. It is just a trade name. And while you can use dialogbboxes for some options, certainly not for all of them. The command line options ARE yoused by the Intel compiler even on Windows. The dialog boxes just pre-set some of those flags for you.

Comment: I tried static compilation but it doesn't make any difference. I have submitted a support request with Intel but they don't seem to understand the issue. I think a computer scans requests for key words and sends a canned reply. I am trying again.